# Return string and function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function

I have a rails helper method that is called by:

```
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Product", f, :products %>
```

in application_helper.rb:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
     render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  "<div>BLAHBLAHBLAH</div>" +
  link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_fields', data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub('\n', '')})+ ""
end
```

But this returns everything visible as text on the web page. How do I return both the div and the link_to, so they are both rendered correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
"<div>BLAHBLAHBLAH</div> #{link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_fields', data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub('\n', '')})}".html_safe
```

Note the use of [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe). Remember that Rails will write your unescaped HTML code as a plain 'ol string to help prevent issues like [Html Script Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#HTML_Script_Injection). That's what you were encountering, so you simply need to ensure it is written as actual HTML code.